# Grabbing a string from a continously changing text file in PHP

Tags: php, file

Well, I have a text file that constantly changes. The part of the text file is this important line:

`e=username`

The username part of it changes constantly, but I need to capture the `username` part of `e=username` string **and put it into a variable** every time it changes. Problem is I don't know how to. The file name is replace.txt

Comment: What part is problematic? Monitoring the file for changes (as marcog has advised on) or reading the file and extracting the value?

Comment: I dont want to monitor the file for changes, I just want to put that ever changing username part of e= to a variable

Comment: Do you need help extracting the `username` from `e=username`?

Comment: @marcog Yes, exactly. And every time the file changes too.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Hopefully you can work it out from there, otherwise you'll need to give more information.

Answer (score 4):

[`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) returns the time the file was last modified. Poll this timestamp every so often and read the file to check for a new `e=username` entry if the timestamp is later than the previous time you checked.

The timestamp is given in seconds, so there's no point checking it more than once a second. If you need more frequent updates, you'll have to read the file continuously as the last modified time is stored with second accuracy.

To extract `username` from `e=username`, you can use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (preg_match("/^e=(.+)$/", "e=username", $matches))
    print $matches[1];
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a key piece of info!

Comment: @Galilsnap What part about putting it into a variable do you need help with?

Comment: Remember that e=username is always changing, so one time it might be e=john or e=potatoes

Comment: @Gal So make the necessary changes. Is it that difficult to realise that you can use a variable in place of the string literal `"e=username"` in the code above?